# Recognize which technology is used on a nfc card?

Tags: nfc

I have a nfc card which supports multiple technologies. (For example NfcA,MifareClassic, ISOdep). I want to understand what technology has been used to write to the tag.
Are these technologies independent? I mean can I use mifareclassic to write some data and use NfcA (or ISOdep) to read that data?
Or these technologies each have their own memory?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have been reading a lot about this subject last few days but have not found a good reference. 
I also did some tests myself. I wrote an android app to write a NdefMessage to a tag. and I found the corresponding data bytes when I used MifareClassic APIs to dump the memory.

I took a look at the code inside MifareClassic library, and found out that all of the relative functions(e.g readblock,writeblock) create a byte array and pass it to transceive(). In android documention it is mentioned that calling MifareClassic.transceive is the same as calling NfcA.transceive.

which is a bit ironic since it is mentioned in NfcA documents that NfcA and MifareClassic are not the same and they have different transmission protocols.

another thing that I realized was that Ndef is not a protocol by itself. it a standard format to store data. apparently Ndef class has different implementations for different tags. on a MifareClassic tag you can only use Ndef class to write data to it if the tag is using the default keys. otherwise you will not be able to write to the tag.